# jQuery select option elements by value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a select element wrapped by a span element. I am not allowed to use the select id but I am allowed to use the span id.
I am trying to write a javascript/jquery function in which the input is a number i, which is one of the values of the select's options. The function will turn the relevant option to selected.

```
<span id="span_id">
    <select id="h273yrjdfhgsfyiruwyiywer" multiple="multiple">
        <option value="1">cleaning</option>
        <option value="2">food-2</option>
        <option value="3">toilet</option>
        <option value="4">baby</option>
        <option value="6">knick-knacks</option>
        <option value="9">junk-2</option>
        <option value="10">cosmetics</option>
    </select>
</span>
```

I wrote something as follows (this does not completely work, which is why I am posting this question):

```
function select_option(i) {

    options = $('#span_id').children('select').children('option');
    //alert(options.length); //7
    //alert(options[0]); //[object HTMLOptionElement]
    //alert(options[0].val()); //not a jquery element
    //alert(options[0].value); //1

    //the following does not seem to work since the elements of options are DOM ones not jquery's
    option = options.find("[value='" + i + "']");
    //alert(option.attr("value")); //undefined
    option.attr('selected', 'selected');

}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 156, accepted):

Here's the simplest solution with a clear selector:

```
function select_option(i) {
  return $('span#span_id select option[value="' + i + '"]').html();
}
```

Comment: `$.escapeSelector(i)` may be better than `i`.

Answer (score 37):

With jQuery > 1.6.1 should be better to use this syntax:

```
$('#span_id select option[value="' + some_value + '"]').prop('selected', true);
```

Answer (score 30):

Just wrap your option in $(option) to make it act the way you want it to.  You can also make the code shorter by doing

```
$('#span_id > select > option[value="input your i here"]').attr("selected", "selected")
```

Answer (score 7):

```
options = $("#span_id>select>option[value='"+i+"']");
option = options.text();
alert(option);
```

**here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/hRFYF/**

Answer (score 7):

You can use .val() to select the value, like the following:

```
function select_option(i) {
    $("#span_id select").val(i);
}
```

Here is a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tweissin/uscq42xh/8/

Comment: On which browser/platform didn't it work for you?  On Mac/Chrome, it successfully selects an item in the list, which is exactly what the original question was.

Comment: @Mr.Llama, you may have misunderstood the question. @tom's code does what was asked: given a value `i`, select the ith `option` in the `select`. OP was not trying to filter the options.

Comment: Only proposed solution that worked for me.
However it doesn't work with multiple selects.

Answer (score 3):

To get the value just use this:

```
<select id ="ari_select" onchange = "getvalue()">
<option value = "1"></option>
<option value = "2"></option>
<option value = "3"></option>
<option value = "4"></option>
</select>

<script>
function getvalue()
{
    alert($("#ari_select option:selected").val()); 
}
</script>
```

this will fetch the values

Answer (score 1):

```
function select_option(index)
{
    var optwewant;
    for (opts in $('#span_id').children('select'))
    {
        if (opts.value() = index)
        {
            optwewant = opts;
            break;
        }
    }
    alert (optwewant);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I don't know what the internal implementation of jQuery is, but the other solutions look simpler.

Comment: If you already have jQuery those are easier, but I figured you might want to know a pure js way of doing it.

Answer (score 1):

You can change with simple javascript

```js
document.querySelector('#h273yrjdfhgsfyiruwyiywer').value='4'
```

```html
<span id="span_id">
    <select id="h273yrjdfhgsfyiruwyiywer" multiple="multiple">
        <option value="1">cleaning</option>
        <option value="2">food-2</option>
        <option value="3">toilet</option>
        <option value="4">baby</option>
        <option value="6">knick-knacks</option>
        <option value="9">junk-2</option>
        <option value="10">cosmetics</option>
    </select>
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#h273yrjdfhgsfyiruwyiywer").children('[value="' + i + '"]').prop("selected", true);
```