# could not get input field value in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am creating an input field using `foreach` loop like this

```
<?php foreach($data as $key=>$val) { ?>
<td class="table-td-1">  
<input readonly class="form-control" name="model[]" id="typename" type="text" value="<?php echo $val['asset']; ?>">
</td>
<?php } ?>
```

$data is Array

```
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [asset_id] => abc-02
            [asset_name] => Freezer
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [asset_id] => xyz-01
            [asset_name] => Refrigerator
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [asset_id] => 300001
            [asset_name] => Generator
        )
)
```

and in javascript, I am trying to get the value using this code but it always alerts first value of the input.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function () {
           var typename = $('#typename').val();
           alert(typename);     
});
</script>
```

i have to disable this input field when value is 'Generator'

Comment: you use same id for every input so you always get first value.

Comment: change the id of `input` field while iterating

Comment: so what else you expecting?

Comment: @IronyStack different value for every input field

Comment: @RonyLoud how will i get value in javascript then?for diferent id,s?

Comment: first of all you have called `alert()` once only. you have to differentiate `id`s first and call alert based on those `id`s as per your need

Comment: Use jquery each function

Comment: what's the status of this question? you've been given many answers, but none was accepted.

Comment: @Fred-ii- none was satisfactory

Comment: you've been given 10 answers but commented under 1.

Comment: all were asking to change id which i can't

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php foreach($data as $key=>$val) { ?>
<td class="table-td-1 status">  
<input readonly class="form-control" name="model[]" id="typename" type="text" value="<?php echo $val['asset']; ?>">
</td>
<?php } ?>
```

And in jquery

```
$(document).on('change','.status',function(){
        var $status = $(this).val();
        if($status == 'not_working'){
            $(this).closest('tr').find('.reason').removeAttr('disabled');
        }
    });
```

`reason` is class you have to give which input field you want to disable

Answer (score 1):

You should **never** use same id for several elements.

Update you code for debug, and you'll see that you have an array:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function () {
           var typename = $('[name="model[]"]')
              .toArray().map(e => e.value);
           alert(JSON.stringify(typename));
});
</script>
```

You should update your php, to set different id for each element drawn in a cycle, i.e:

```
<?php $i=1;foreach($nomatter as $a) {?>
<input id="typename_<?=$i++?>">
<?php } ?>
```

So you'll be able to address eash input separately:

```
       var typename = $('#typename_1').val();
```

Comment: same result. it only alert first value

Comment: update your question with var_dump($data), what is the $data ?

Comment: actually i have to disable some fields on the basis of '#typename'.val so i cannot get it seperaely

Comment: once again,.. you should "NEVER" use same id, any functionality may not work, so use class instead of id, and redo you "disable some fields", and the problem (I'm almost sure) you have in $data, so please share it, for other be able to help ;)

Comment: Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [asset_id] => abc-02
            [asset_name] => Freezer
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [asset_id] => xyz-01
            [asset_name] => Refrigerator
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [asset_id] => 300001
            [asset_name] => Generator
        )
)

Comment: not for me )) update your question, if you still have a trouble

Comment: please look at question now and yes i still have problem

Comment: sorry, I was wrong, you need to add .toArray().map(e => e.value) to transform jquery result to values

Comment: it is giving me an array, now what i have to do for disabling any input field for specific values?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7290950/jquery-select-option-elements-by-value

Answer (score 1):

Use class instead of duplicate id like this.

```
<?php foreach($data as $key=>$val) { ?>
<td class="table-td-1">  
<input readonly class="form-control clsValue" name="model[]" id="typename" type="text" value="<?php echo $val['asset']; ?>">
</td>
<?php } ?>
```

And in jquery loop your class and get value using `this` instant..

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $( ".clsValue" ).each(function( index ) {
          var typename = $(this).val();
           alert(typename);     
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```js
$('[readonly].form-control').each(function(i,e) {

    console.log($(e).val());

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<td class="table-td-1">  
  <input readonly class="form-control" name="model[]" id="typename" type="text" value="1">  
  <input readonly class="form-control" name="model[]" id="typename" type="text" value="2">  
  <input readonly class="form-control" name="model[]" id="typename" type="text" value="3">  
  <input readonly class="form-control" name="model[]" id="typename" type="text" value="4"> 
  <input readonly class="form-control" name="model[]" id="typename" type="text" value="5">
</td>
```

1. `.val()` called once will always produce only one value; [`.val()` docs](https://api.jquery.com/val/):

   > Get the current value of the first element in the set of matched elements .
2. HTML `id` attribute is supposed to be unique, try this instead.

---

```
<?php 
   $count = 0;
   foreach($data as $key=>$val) { 
?>
    <td class="table-td-1">  
        <input readonly class="form-control" name="model[]" id="typename_<?php echo $count++; ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo $val['asset']; ?>">
    </td>

<?php } ?>
```

It'll produce different `id` attributes for each input, `typename_0`, `typename_1`, ..., `typename_n`, allowing you to for example:

```js
$('[id^="typename_"]').each(function(i,e) {

    console.log($(e).val());

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <td class="table-td-1">  
      <input readonly class="form-control" name="model[]" id="typename_0" type="text" value="1">  
      <input readonly class="form-control" name="model[]" id="typename_1" type="text" value="2">  
      <input readonly class="form-control" name="model[]" id="typename_2" type="text" value="3">  
      <input readonly class="form-control" name="model[]" id="typename_3" type="text" value="4"> 
      <input readonly class="form-control" name="model[]" id="typename_4" type="text" value="5">
    </td>
```

Where `[id^="typename_"]` is [CSS attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors), matching all elements with an `id` attribute starting with `typename_`.

Answer (score 0):

try this , 
this will call alert function for each input with `form-control` class

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
          $(".form-control").each(function(){

           alert($(this).val());
     })  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Set  **class="typename"** instead of  **id="typename"**:

```
   <?php foreach($data as $key=>$val) { ?>
    <td class="table-td-1">  
    <input readonly class="form-control" name="model[]" class="typename" type="text" value="<?php echo $val['asset']; ?>">
    </td>
    <?php } ?>
```

You can get values like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function () {
           var typename1 = $('.typename')[0].val();
           var typename2 = $('.typename')[1].val();
           alert(typename1);     
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

there is a big mistake in your code, you can't use same id for multiple input fields, when the loop run multiple input fields will create with same id, you have to make the id dynamic, you can make the id dynamic by appending some unique value to the id each time you create an input field the use that id to fetch the data.

Please let me know if you need sample code.

Answer (score 0):

The id attribute specifies a unique id for an HTML element it's not a good practice to use same ID more than once on a page, instead of ID attribute loop the class attribute in jquery.

```js
 <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function () {
     $('.common-class').each(function() {
      alert($(this).val());
     });
        
    });
 </script>
```

```html
  <?php $incr_var = 1; ?>
  <?php foreach($data as $key=>$val) { ?>
    <td class="table-td-1">  
    <input readonly class="form-control common-class" name="model[]" id="typename<?php echo $incr_var ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo $val['asset']; ?>">
    </td>
    <?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

pure js approach;

replace id with class;

```
<?php foreach($data as $key=>$val) { ?>
<td class="table-td-1">  
<input readonly class="form-control typename" name="model[]" type="text" value="<?php echo $val['asset']; ?>">
</td>
<?php } ?>
```

js

```
window.onload = alertTypeNames();

function alertTypeNames() {
    document.getElementsByClassName('typename').map((inputTag) => {     
        alert(inputTag.value);
         return true;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you fired with your id that's why it's fired only first element value.

this is how you can do that with your current code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('input[name="model[]"]').each(function(){
       alert($(this).val());
    });
});
```

However, it's highly recommended that you have to used unique id for each element otherwise used class to do what you want to.

Answer (score 0):

Element id should be unique. And try it inside on event because dynamically adding elements will not grab ready state.

http://api.jquery.com/live/